# Date comparision in MariaDB after upgrading from Debian 8 to Debian 9

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, upgrade

I upgraded from Debian 8 to Debian 9 and everything is fine with one exception.

A query filter based on date comparison.

```
SELECT id_mass_rich, data_ora_car FROM `eps_massiva_richiesta` WHERE data_ora_car > '2019-12-05 24:00:00' ORDER BY data_ora_car DESC
```

In the results I find records of 2018 year.

[image: select query results]

Where is the problem ?

Comment: is the column `data_ora_car ` a `DATETIME` type as it should or is it a `CHAR(..)` or `VARCHAR(..)` type?.. And what is the time `24:00:00` ?

Comment: Thanks, tre problem is the hour 24:00:00. It does not exists

Comment: Sounds like the 'strict' option came into effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the time. The `24:00:00` does not exists.
Use next day and time `00:00:00`